# Отличие альтернативного набора стилей от предпочтительного

Tags: css, html5, css3, style

Чем отличается альтернативный набор стилей от предпочтительного? Вопрос касается элемента `link` с атрибутом `rel="stylesheet"`. Понятно, что добавив атрибут `title` вроде как создается еще один предпочтительный набор стилей. Но чем это отличается от того же `rel="alternate stylesheet"`? Там также можно добавить атрибут `title`. По сути и то, и то, просто дополнительные наборы стилей? Для чего же тогда значение `alternate`?

```
<!-- a persistent style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">

<!-- the preferred alternate style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="green.css" title="Green styles">

<!-- some alternate style sheets -->
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="contrast.css" title="High contrast">
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть три типа: постоянная, предпочитаемая или альтернативная таблица:

1. Авторы могут указать ряд взаимоисключающих таблиц стилей, называемых
   **альтернативными**. Пользователи могут выбирать таблицы, которые им
   больше нравятся. Например, автор может указать один стиль для
   небольших экранов, другой - для слабовидящих пользователей
   (например, с использованием крупного шрифта). Агенты пользователей
   должны предоставлять пользователям возможности выбора одной из
   альтернативных таблиц.
2. Автор может указать, что одна из альтернатив является
   **предпочтительной**. Агенты пользователей должны применять
   предпочитаемые автором таблицы стилей, если пользователь не выбрал
   другую альтернативу.
   Авторы могут сгруппировать несколько альтернативных таблиц стилей
   (включая предпочитаемые автором) под одним именем стиля. Если
   пользователь выбирает именованный стиль, агент пользователя должен
   применять все таблицы стилей с этим именем. Агенты пользователей не
   должны применять альтернативные таблицы стилей с другим именем
   стиля. Как присвоить имя группе стилей, описано в разделе об
   определении внешних таблиц стилей.
3. Авторы также могут указать **постоянные** таблицы стилей, которые агенты
   пользователей должны применять в дополнение к альтернативным
   таблицам стилей.

---

- Чтобы таблицы была постоянной, установите для атрибута `rel` значение `"stylesheet"`, и не устанавливайте атрибут `title`.
- Чтобы таблица была предпочитаемой, установите для атрибута `rel` значение `"stylesheet"`, и дайте таблице имя с помощью атрибута `title`.
- Чтобы указать альтернативную таблицу, установите для атрибута `rel` значение `"alternate stylesheet"` а дайте таблице имя с помощью атрибута `title`.

[Больше информации](http://citforum.ru/internet/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.3.1).

Comment: Не не, как раз наоборот. В спецификации html5 сказано, что атрибут title указывает на альтернативную таблицу стилей https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-style-title
Т.е. и rel="alternate stylesheet" и "title" в элементе style указывает на альтернативную таблицу стилей?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, уточнение деталей можно посмотреть в спецификации, конечно, я привёл выдержку из человеческого, даже рабочего, описания.

Comment: А где в спецификации html5 описание альтернативной и предпочтительной таблицы стилей? Или в какой-то другой это описано? Эти три типа вроде как взяты из html4, а она же устарела?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, не всё, что в 4-ке - по умолчанию устарело, даже больше - многое переносится в новом, лучшем виде.

Comment: что переносится-то это понятно. но в данном случае я считаю это недоработка спецификации. описание предпочтительного и альтернативного стилей не перенесли в html5 (там нет описания)

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, ну если учесть что там каждый чих должен быть задокументирован, то совсем неудивительно что что-то могли пропустить. Главное что работает. Вроде.